# How can I alter previous/next word navigation in Eclipse editor?

Tags: eclipse, ide, editor

When navigating across words, the Eclipse editor considers a change in letter case and a hyphen-minus as word boundaries. This is problematic, as most of my variable names are of mixed case and, with some syntax (e.g. CSS), a hypen-minus can be part of a name.

How can I modify Eclipse to change its understanding of a word boundary to accomodate these common variants of syntax?

[**If it’s not possible, please do not submit an answer**, although such comments are welcome as comments, below.]

Comment: I was looking for something similar and came across vRapper - vim editing in eclipse. BUT: for my use I finally considered it to be overkill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Preferences -> Java -> Editor.
```

Disable "Smart caret positioning...".

Comment: Hmm, that removed the case-change boundary, but not the hyphen-minus boundary.

Comment: I would guess that stopping at hyphens is the platform specific way of navigating by word.  Disabling the smart caret positioning preference will make the caret move as is the default for your OS, so compare it to notepad or textedit and behavior should be the same.

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg I don't think you are right - e.g. ().getAttribute(funny_name).getValue()+"." will stop for my notepad 3 times. But in eclipse it stops 17 times. Especially the stops which only move 1 character are ridiculus, I could just press left for that.